# Trouble registering a custom taxonomy for my Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type of 'Employees' and am trying to register custom categories for this custom post type.  Here is my php:

```
//---------------------------------------------------//
//---- REGISTER CUSTOM POST TYPES ------------------//
//--------------------------------------------------//

// Register Employees Custom Post Type
function employees_custom_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => 'Employees',
        'singular_name'         => 'Employee',
        'menu_name'             => 'Employees',
        'name_admin_bar'        => 'Employee',
        'archives'              => 'Item Archives',
        'parent_item_colon'     => 'Parent Item:',
        'all_items'             => 'All Items',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Add New Item',
        'add_new'               => 'Add New',
        'new_item'              => 'New Item',
        'edit_item'             => 'Edit Item',
        'update_item'           => 'Update Item',
        'view_item'             => 'View Item',
        'search_items'          => 'Search Item',
        'not_found'             => 'Not found',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'Not found in Trash',
        'featured_image'        => 'Featured Image',
        'set_featured_image'    => 'Set featured image',
        'remove_featured_image' => 'Remove featured image',
        'use_featured_image'    => 'Use as featured image',
        'insert_into_item'      => 'Insert into item',
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => 'Uploaded to this item',
        'items_list'            => 'Items list',
        'items_list_navigation' => 'Items list navigation',
        'filter_items_list'     => 'Filter items list',
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => 'Employee',
        'description'           => 'A List of CenterPoint Employees categorized by role',
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'team_categories' ),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,        
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'post_type', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'employees_custom_post_type', 0 );

//-----------------------------------//
//----REGISTER CUSTOM TAXONOMIES-----//
//-----------------------------------//

function custom_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Team Categories',
        'singular_name'              => 'Team Category',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Taxonomy',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Items',
        'parent_item'                => 'Parent Item',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Item:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New Item Name',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Item',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Item',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Item',
        'view_item'                  => 'View Item',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate items with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove items',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used',
        'popular_items'              => 'Popular Items',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Items',
        'not_found'                  => 'Not Found',
        'no_terms'                   => 'No items',
        'items_list'                 => 'Items list',
        'items_list_navigation'      => 'Items list navigation',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'team_categories', array( 'employees_custom_post_type' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy', 0 );
```

My custom taxonomy is not showing up in the admin.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should give the proper name on this line:
    register_post_type( 'post_type', $args );
Shouldnt it be `employees_custom_post_type`?